# Visual Studio Code: How to check unit tests coverage for Python unittests?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I have unit tests written in Python's [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) library but I'm not sure how to check unit test coverage. I'm using VS Code version 1.68.1.

Comment: if the test runner can't instrument the interpreter to give feedback of the line executed you have a problem. Are there python test runners that can give coverage?